# How to log the key-value pair with logging API in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

First criteria is I am using logging API/module and I can't change now to any other library.

I want to have my log file written like below with key-value pair.

```
2017-03-26 00:34:02,760 - root - WARNING - There is something burning. Where=Kitchen House=Alice
```

So in here `Where=Kitchen` and `House=Alice` are key value pair.

I know I can do this

```
>>> logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
>>> logging.warning('There is something burning')
```

But it will print

```
2017-03-26 00:34:02,760 - root - WARNING - There is something burning
```

So I want a technique that will take key-value pair and will in the log file as = and that shouldn't be passed as message. It needs to be passed as separate argument.

Comment: What precise behaviour are you expecting? You haven't included those placeholders in the format string, or made those key-value pairs part of the message.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I know. I just gave it a shot. I know there are something wrong in there.

Comment: So are you expecting it to take an arbitrary dictionary and format all pairs like that? Put specific values in specific places? What?

Comment: I am expecting. It should take an arbitrary dictionary and show it as Key=Value pair.

Comment: +1 I think the question is perfectly clear... also, in java logging (logback), there is a possibility to put arbitrary key-value pairs to the so called 'mapped diagnostic context' (MDC) which are then automatically logged each time you send a logging entry

Answer (score 2):

Something like this. Don't hate me.

```
>>> d = {'Where':'Kitchen', 'House':'Alice'}
>>> message = 'There is something burning. {0}'.format(
...     ', '.join(
...         ('{0}={1}'.format(k, v) for k, v in d.items())
...     )
... )
>>> message
'There is something burning. Where=Kitchen, House=Alice'
```

Comment: I want to use the `logging` API.

Comment: You can use this in any output API you like, it doesn't matter. This is about message construction.